# vowpal wabbit python3 interface installation on OSX 10.13.2, python 3.5.1, Anaconda3

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.5, vowpalwabbit

I'm installing vowpal wabbit python3 interface using OSX 10.13.2, python 3.5.1, Anaconda3 virtual env for Anaconda.
I've followed this step.

```
# edit Makefile
# change BOOST_INCLUDE to use anaconda env dir: /anaconda/envs/vw/include
# change BOOST_LIBRARY to use anaconda lib dir: /anaconda/envs/vw/lib
```

I've followed the step above.

https://gist.github.com/suisuiwudi/86f9657d785b3e4fdc02e11e3e35899b

I got the error, please check the details in the gist above.

```
ld: library not found for -lpython3.5m
```

I also followed their methods, but these didn't work.

https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/issues/1267
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/2871

Any idea about how to install these on MAC?

Comment: question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `nlp` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed)

Comment: Did you try to run `vowpal_wabbit/python/conda_install.sh`? it was developed for Linux, but it aim to install all needed packages within a conda environment instead of global OS environment, and as such much turn out to work out of the box (or not- i have no idea)

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi I tried that, but nothing changed.

Comment: @RuiShu do you mean that you got identical error message? If so, then I can not help, as I do not have experience with MAC, unfortunately :(

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi Thanks!

Comment: I looked into it a bit. Your error appears inside of this compilation instruction: https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/543dc5e023932146829b501be73ac32824820599/python/Makefile#L55. You can identify that `-lpython3.5m` is part of `$(BOOST_LIBRARY) $(PYTHON_LDFLAGS)` (just from the preceding and following arguments). I can not see anywhere `BOOST_LIBRARY` being appended with it. So I guess it is part of `PYTHON_LDFLAGS` (unless you have a custom `USER_BOOST_LIBRARY`). If so, I would check `ls -l /anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/libpy*` and start by understanding what you have.

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi 
```ls -l /anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/libpy*

-rwxrwxr-x  2 SHURUI  staff  5997592 Apr 26 06:46 /anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/libpython3.6m.a

-rwxrwxr-x  1 SHURUI  staff  3037196 May 22 21:44 /anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib
``` I got libpython3.6m.dylib which is weird.. Thanks for the instructions, I would try to find where it came from.

Comment: python3.6 is my anaconda python version. I want to use python3.5 for my project. I think they may not use virtual env for this.

Comment: I use different python versions for different environments in conda on Linux. So it seems to work at least there. One trivial question, how did you create your `python35` environment? Another line of debugging: try to execute `shell python3.5-config --ldflags` (good sign is that vowpal_wabbit/python/setup.py correctly identifies your vitrenv python version, but it is indeed puzzling why do you habe 3.6 library installed)

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration of the system might be a problem here it is a very known issue in VowpalWabbit's installation that it doesn't work with MacOSX because a dependency BoostC++(in which all the reductions are implemented i.e in C++) requires a file named libstdC++ and this file was discontinued by Apple 2 years ago. Also I wouldn't recommend using Anaconda along with it although users having installation problems with Anaconda was resolved in an issue but just to be on the safe side. This is due to the dynamic linking nature of the libraries used in it namely Cmake and boost-python.
Really there are two solutions to your problem
1) Find an older version of Xcode and copy that file into its required path
2) Using a virtual machine with Windows or linux installed and install VowpalWabbit there
Apple does sometimes annoy even its most loyal customers.